# Why does this JavaScript work in <script> tag but not with src

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
window.onload = function siteTitle() {
const element = document.getElementById("site-title");
element.innerHTML = "New Heading";
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="siteTitle()">
        <h1 id="site-title" class="title">Site Title</h1>
        <div class="box-container">
        <div class="left-box">
            a
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
            <h1 class="title-in">abc</h1>
            a
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing it multiple times with things I have found from other questions and website but I cannot fix this
The script worked when placed directly in the  tag but not when imported
Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'm clueless as well .. anyway why using `onload="siteTitle()"` and also attaching the event handler via js? if you wanted the first strategy to work you needed a function named `siteTitle` defined in your js anyhow

Comment: You can't use both `<body onload="XXX">` and also `window.onload = YYY`, because they both use the same `onload` property.

Comment: this is all kinds of wrong. there is no function named `siteTitle`. what you're doing in that `window.onload=` part is "if that function get's a parameter (it doesn't), put it in a var called "siteTitle". Ditch all that. simply create an [event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Comment: @Konrad I cant check the console, inspect element is blocked by admin

Comment: @hjh, as a web developer, console and element inspection are required tools. Go talk to your admin and have them unblock it.

Comment: @mykaf Sorry, that won't work. Inspect element was disabled because it is considered a distraction by my school district

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes works for me well.
If these codes doesn't work for you, check your browser and update it.

try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="site-title" class="title">Site Title</h1>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="left-box">a</div>
      <div class="right-box">
        <h1 class="title-in">abc</h1>
        a
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

with

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById("site-title");
  element.innerHTML = "New Heading";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the function from `<body onload="siteTitle()">` you need to define it with a normal function definition, not by assigning to `window.onload`.

```
function siteTitle () {
    const element = document.getElementById("site-title");
    element.innerHTML = "New Heading";
};
```